# Construct list terminated with a different type

Tags: functional-programming, f#

Do I need a bespoke sum type to be able to define a data type that is a list of type A, where the last element is of type B (and thus have to reimplement all the nice functions defined on it).

```
type ListTerminatedWith<'a,'b> = 
    | Cons of 'a * ListTerminatedWith<'a,'b> 
    | Nil of 'b
```

ok, so the obvious thing is:

```
type ListTerminatedWith<'a,'b> = List<'a> * 'b
```

but, actually I only want to append the terminating value to the list when I get there (really the question is about Seq<'a>, rather than List<'a>).

A weird example would be lets say the sum of the values as a string.

So (in complete psuedo code...I'm not expecting this to compile)

```
let x: ListTerminatedWith<int,string> = [ 1;2;3;"6"]
```

this value is created by a function, where the "6" is appended, when the function wants to terminate, rather like create a sequence.

Comment: Perhaps you can settle with a list of type `Either<'a, 'b>`? But either way, you'll probably have to write the sum etc functions, as defaults won't work.

Comment: this allows any combination of 'a and 'b...the thing I don't want to reinvent is map/bind/fold etc.....but maybe I'm stuck with it

Comment: Well, you have a very specific case here, I'm afraid you have to, unless both types exhibit a method that can be used with SRTP. In that case, you may be able to use simpler redefines of the standard functions. It's quite common to define map, bind, filter, fold on your own collection types, esp if they cannot be `IEnumerable`.

Comment: it is specific, but in fact, as I've shown, really its a generalisation of List<'a>, where Nil holds a value too. It's quite interesting (to me) that such a trivial extension of List<'a> is in fact seemingly inexpressible without going down to the atomic types.

Comment: Fwiw, you don't have a trivial extension of List, you have your own type. List is defined as `List<'t>`, your type is defined as `MyList<'a, 'b>`. How would any existing code be able to deal with arbitrary type arguments, that, in your case, also have specific rules attached?

Comment: type List<'a> = ListTerminatedWith<'a,Unit>....i.e. these 2 types are isomorphic, for any List<'a> defined by stand f# libraries I can map to the above and back again. So I can embed List<'a> in ListTerminatedWith<'a,Unit>, which to me, informally, means that is an extension....and in some senses, pretty trivial, if I were to write map, bind etc...they would be virtually the same as for List<'a>, just the sort of things our programming languages are designed to avoid.

Comment: I think the penny has dropped....you mean an extension like an OO Liskov type thing?....yes I agree, I didnt mean an OO extension, I meant more in a typeclass sort of way.

Comment: Yeah, type classes are not supported in F#. According to Don Syme they would require a CLR change, so I doubt they come anytime soon.

Comment: well ok...you can simulate them pretty easily...Don Syme is kicking the can down the road, Scala has type classes but they are not present in the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably define your type as either being empty, or being a pair consisting of a list and the terminating value:

```
type TerminatedList<'a, 'b> = 
  | Empty
  | NonEmpty of list<'a> * 'b
```

This makes invalid states unrepresentable, but it also reuses standard list for some part of the representation. You still have to redefine your own standard functions like `map` for your new type, but at least you can often reuse built-in functions for `List`. For example, to define `map`, you can reuse `List.map` with some extra wrapping:

```
module TerminatedList = 
  let map f = function 
    | Empty -> Empty 
    | NonEmpty(a, b) -> NonEmpty(List.map f a, f b)
```

I'm not sure there is a reasonable way to generalize this plumbing (because you typically need to do something special about the extra terminating element), so it might be tedious, but it should be easy to add any functions you need.

Comment: I've used list as the example, because its simple, really the question is about lazy (or at least deferred) evaluation of the terminator, i.e. seq<'a> followed by a 'b, are you familiar with the Eventually Monad, which I think is used in the F# compiler?...its effectively an ListTerminatedWith<Unit,'a>, where a standard List<'a> is a ListTerminatedWith<'a,Unit>

Comment: tbh, I've probably answered my own question...IF the f# compiler had to roll it's own version (effectively of Seq<Unit> terminated with 'a) then its not (obviously) possible.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd As with any monadic type, you should define its `bind`, `return` and `map` and possibly some others for CE's, I doubt that'll ever be "automatic", but have a look at F#+ for some near-HKT. The `Eventually<'T>` of the compiler is here as an example: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/29b833d24b58e35780f697efcaeef8c8134d0d6c/src/absil/illib.fs#L828

Comment: In `TerminatedList.map` how can you have a function (`f`) that operates on both `'a` and `'b`?

Comment: @Abel yes I accept that, but having to build these things from 1st principles on a sum type is more work than, say Tomas's example, really we don't want software engineering to be an exercise in building things that are "primitive"

Comment: @HenrikHansen, same as map on a tuple, you can map on the left or the right, in general many data types admit more that 1 map.

Comment: But as stated above `| NonEmpty(a, b) -> NonEmpty(List.map f a, f b)` it's not possible to specify a function `f`, that can be called for both `a` and `b` unless they are of the same type, and then the entire idea is gone. Or am I missing something?

Comment: so you have 2 maps, one that maps on 'a, and the other that maps on 'b....same as you would define on tuples or Choice<a','b>....or implement "bimap" (though its nice to have canonical maps)....the mentality is a bit of a symptom of not allowing overlapping typeclasses...where a type (or set of types) may admit a typeclass (here Functor a) in more than 1 way.....there's more than 1 way to skin a cat....and there's often more than 1 way to implement "Functor a"

Comment: actually the real problem is....there doesnt seem to be a sensible implementation for bind on 'a....there is on 'b.